# How to remove debugging red dot in VSCode v1.28.2

Tags: visual-studio-code

I casually pressed a key, i don't know which one, i want to remove it from the view, i don't use VScode debugger at all.

[image]

I read the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_breakpoints) but it's unclear.

Comment: If you want to do it with mouse, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72297531/7869636

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> F9

or

> Click on the editor margin

or

> (Top Bar) Debug -> Toggle Breakpoint

or

> (Icon on The left) Debug -> Breakpoint section -> Mouse Over -> Remove all breakpoints

should remove the breakpoint

Comment: clicking on it doesnt do anything, i use mac ( i didnt mention it in the question), i turned on  f1-f12 in mac preferences but that didnt work. I found a solution through Command Palette

Comment: According to https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf F9 should work for mac too.

Answer (score 1):

Search for debug in settings, disable "glyph margin", and all related settings, this will disable the option to make debugging dots, if you just want to remove them all but not disable adding them, use the answers above.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all breakpoints (red dot) you need go to `Command Palette -> Debug` and choose `Remove all breakpoints` from dropdown list.
More is in
[Docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging)