# Can I configure VS Code to disable Breakpoint by middle click?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am switching from PyCharm to VS Codium. I want to be able to disable breakpoints by middle mouse click, like in pycharm.

Currently, I can disable a breakpoint by right click at breakpoint and select Disable Breakpoint:

[image]

Another way is to disable it in list in Breakpoints view.

But I want to be able to quickly enable/disable it by just clicking with mouse wheel (middle button). Is it possible to configure VS Code this way? Currently, when I middle click on breakpoint, this is ignored, and instead a text from selection clipboard is pasted (it is the default behavior in linux). Visual Studio Code version is 1.66.1.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way at the moment to customize mouse click events.  There are a few hardcoded options you can change in the settings, but it is extremely limited like pressing ctrl and the mouse wheel for zoom.  As far as I am aware, disabling breakpoints is not among those options.

Check out: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3130

Answer (score 0):

I currently use the following workaround.

#### Remap the middle click to some button.

For wayland [several utilities](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Wayland#Remap_keyboard_or_mouse_keys) can be used for that. Let's take `kbct`.

Add such config (edit for your needs)
`/etc/kbct/config.yml`:

```yaml
- keyboards: [ "Logitech MX Master" ]

  keymap:
    btn_middle: f15
```

Then start `kbct.service`.

#### Create the ruler script

Make the file `choose_press.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

class=$(xdotool getactivewindow getwindowclassname)

if [ "x$class" == "xVSCodium" ]; then
    ydotool click 0xC1  # right click
    sleep 0.2
    ydotool key 107:1 107:0 28:1 28:0  # End, Enter
else
    ydotool click 0xC2  # middle click
fi
```

Do not forget to add executable permissions.

#### Bind shortcut to the script

To assign a command to shortcut in KDE, go to `System Settings` -> `Shortcuts` -> `Custom Shortcuts`, right click, choose `New` -> `Global Shortcut` -> `Command/URL`. Go to `Action` tab and fill in the command. In this case it will be the path to `choose_press.sh`. Note: do not use ~ there.
And in `Trigger` tab assign the shortcut. In this case we use f15 (use some way to simulate it, if it is not presented on the keyboard).

#### Start VS Codium

Use vs codium in X11 mode. This is because I currently do not know how to get active window class in wayland.

#### Result

Now if you middle click in vscodium window, it will receive the sequence of input that leads to enabling/disabling breakpoint. In any other window, the middle click will behave as normal.

---

There is `debug.enableOrDisableBreakpoint` in codium, but toggling that with shortcut only works when the cursor is on the line with breakpoint. I did not found a way to move cursor to the line where you pressed (method to get the mouse over line?). So I made that complex thing with ydotool choose_press.sh.

I also tried to start stop kbct by window activation, but that is unfortunately broken in kde wayland currently.